# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'companies' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, infinite-scroll, ecmascript-5

I would like to have a list of items with infinite scroll and I am using this package https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller but in the documentation there is nothing mentioned how the fetching function looks like.

In my code I have it like this:

```
this.state = {
  companies: [],
  page: 0,
  resetResult: false,
};

fetchCompanies(page){
  traineeship.getAll(page).then(response => {
    if (response.data) {
      this.setState({ companies: this.state.companies.concat(response.data._embedded.companies) });
    } else {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchCompanies(this.state.page);
}

<InfiniteScroll
  pageStart={0}
  loadMore={this.fetchCompanies}
  hasMore={true || false}
  loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
  useWindow={false}
>
  {
    this.state.companies.map((traineeship, key) => (
      <div id={"item"} key={key}>
        <div className={"companyInfo"}>
          <div className={"heading"}>
            <div id={"companyDiv"}>
              <p style={{
                fontSize: '18px',
                lineHeight: '18px'
              }}>{traineeship.name}</p>
            </div>
            {
              traineeship.video === null
                ? ''
                :
                <div id={"videoDiv"}>
                  <div className={"youtubeBox center"}>
                    <div id={"youtubeIcon"}>
                      <a className={"primaryColor"}
                        href={traineeship.mediaUrl}>
                        <span style={{ marginRight: '3px' }}><Image
                          src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c545.png"
                          style={{
                            width: '24px',
                            height: '17px'
                          }} /></span>
                        <span> <p style={{
                          fontSize: '13px',
                          lineHeight: '18px',
                          margin: 0,
                          display: 'inline-block'
                        }}>Esittely</p></span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id={"txtVideo"}>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            }

          </div>
          <div className={"location"}>
            <div id={"locationIcon"}>
              <Image src="assets/img/icLocation.png" style={{ marginTop: '-7px' }} />
            </div>
            <div id={"address"}>
              <a href={"https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + encodeURI("Fredrikinkatu 4, Helsinki")}>
                <p className={"primaryColor"}
                  style={{ fontSize: '13px' }}>{traineeship.city}(show in
                                                        map)</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={"companyDescription"}>
            <p className={"secondaryColor"} style={{
              fontSize: '14px',
              lineHeight: '20px'
            }}>{traineeship.description}</p>
          </div>

          <div className={"companyContacts"} style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
            <p className={"contactInfo"}>URL: {traineeship.website}</p>
            <p className={"contactInfo"}>Email: {traineeship.email}</p>
            <p className={"contactInfo"}>Puh: {traineeship.phonenumber}</p>
            <p className={"contactInfo"}>Contact: {traineeship.contact}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
  }
</InfiniteScroll>
```

Full message error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'companies' of
>   undefined
>       at eval (traineeships.component.js:71)

Edit: (I no longer have the error but loadmore seems not trigger at all)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import FourthView from '../fourthview/fourthview.component';
import {Bootstrap, Grid, Row, Col, Button, Image, Modal, Popover} from 'react-bootstrap';
import traineeship from './traineeship.api';
import Header from '../header/header.component';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';

require('./traineeship.style.scss');

class Traineeship extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            companies: [],
            page: 0,
            resetResult: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchCompanies(this.state.page);
    }

    fetchCompanies(page){
        traineeship.getAll(page).then(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                this.setState({companies: this.state.companies.concat(response.data._embedded.companies)});
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"wrapperDiv"}>
                {JSON.stringify(this.props.rootState)}
                <div className={"flexDivCol"}>
                    <div id="header">
                        <Header/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="result">
                        <div className={"search"}>
                            <h2>Harjoittelupaikkoja</h2>
                            <p className={"secondaryColor"}>{this.state.companies.length} paikkaa löydetty</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className={"filters"}>
                            <h5 style={{marginTop: '30px', marginBottom: '10px'}} className={"primaryColor"}>
                                Hakukriteerit</h5>
                            <div className={"filter"}>Ravintola- ja cateringala</div>
                            <div className={"filter"}>Tarjoilija</div>
                            <div className={"filter"}>Kaikki</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className={"searchResults"}>
                            <h5 style={{marginTop: '30px', marginBottom: '10px'}} className={"primaryColor"}>
                                Hakutulokset</h5>

                            <InfiniteScroll
                                pageStart={0}
                                loadMore={() => this.fetchCompanies.bind(this)}
                                hasMore={true || false}
                                loader={<div className="loader" key={0}>Loading ...</div>}
                                useWindow={false}
                            >
                                {
                                    this.state.companies.map((traineeship, key) => (
                                        <div id={"item"} key={key}>
                                            <div className={"companyInfo"}>
                                                <div className={"heading"}>
                                                    <div id={"companyDiv"}>
                                                        <p style={{
                                                            fontSize: '18px',
                                                            lineHeight: '18px'
                                                        }}>{traineeship.name}</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    {
                                                        traineeship.video === null
                                                            ? ''
                                                            :
                                                            <div id={"videoDiv"}>
                                                                <div className={"youtubeBox center"}>
                                                                    <div id={"youtubeIcon"}>
                                                                        <a className={"primaryColor"}
                                                                           href={traineeship.mediaUrl}>
                                                                        <span style={{marginRight: '3px'}}><Image
                                                                            src="http://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c545.png"
                                                                            style={{
                                                                                width: '24px',
                                                                                height: '17px'
                                                                            }}/></span>
                                                                            <span> <p style={{
                                                                                fontSize: '13px',
                                                                                lineHeight: '18px',
                                                                                margin: 0,
                                                                                display: 'inline-block'
                                                                            }}>Esittely</p></span>
                                                                        </a>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div id={"txtVideo"}>

                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                    }

                                                </div>
                                                <div className={"location"}>
                                                    <div id={"locationIcon"}>
                                                        <Image src="assets/img/icLocation.png" style={{marginTop: '-7px'}}/>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div id={"address"}>
                                                        <a href={"https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + encodeURI("Fredrikinkatu 4, Helsinki")}>
                                                            <p className={"primaryColor"}
                                                               style={{fontSize: '13px'}}>{traineeship.city}(show in
                                                                map)</p>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className={"companyDescription"}>
                                                    <p className={"secondaryColor"} style={{
                                                        fontSize: '14px',
                                                        lineHeight: '20px'
                                                    }}>{traineeship.description}</p>
                                                </div>

                                                <div className={"companyContacts"} style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>
                                                    <p className={"contactInfo"}>URL: {traineeship.website}</p>
                                                    <p className={"contactInfo"}>Email: {traineeship.email}</p>
                                                    <p className={"contactInfo"}>Puh: {traineeship.phonenumber}</p>
                                                    <p className={"contactInfo"}>Contact: {traineeship.contact}</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </InfiniteScroll>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Traineeship;
```

So basically it just shows only first five article, page is not increasing!

Comment: Can you post the whole Component class? Specifically, where is your render function?

Comment: @zanerock look at the Edit section!

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I missed the scroll on the div. ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Mizlul: Does fetchCompanies invoked every time scroll happens ? Can you please check that ? Also you are mutating the state here, this.state.companies.concat(response.data._embedded.companies)..

Can you update it to ,

```
const companies = Array.from(this.state.companies);

this.setState({ companies: companies.concat(response.data._embedded.companies) });
```

Comment: changes nothing seem to be different!

Comment: You updated the code and checked ? or you mentioning there is no difference in the code ?

Comment: At first I thought it was mutating also, but [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):
> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

Comment: the problem seems more to be with the loadmore not triggering

Comment: @Mizlul: I just happened to see the jsfiddle for infinite scroll. https://codepen.io/alantseng/pen/WQqePr. not sure if it will be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that `.bind(this)`. Try making your method an arrow function (to implicitly bind the `this` context):

```js
constructor() {
   // ...
   this.fetchCompanies = this.fetchCompanies.bind(this);
}    

fetchCompanies(page) {
  return traineeship.getAll(page).then(response => {
    if (response.data) {
      this.setState({
        companies: this.state.companies.concat(
          response.data._embedded.companies
        )
      });
    } else {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}


// In your render's return:
<InfiniteScroll
  pageStart={0}
  loadMore={() => this.fetchCompanies(this.state.page)}
  hasMore={true || false}
  loader={
    <div className="loader" key={0}>
      Loading ...
    </div>
  }
  useWindow={false}
>;
```

Comment: Unexpected token (27:19)

  25 | 
  26 |     // Arrow function method
> 27 |     fetchCompanies = (page) =>
     |                                   ^

Comment: @Mizlul Sorry, I fixed it. You need to pass in a `page` value to `fetchCompanies`. I put in `this.state.page`, but you might need to adjust that to the value you need.

Comment: I still get Unexpected token

Comment: Your class now looks like this? https://gist.github.com/reeddunkle/010e45710c50698bd5ac143f9b317653

Comment: still same error unexpected token, looks like I cannot define arrow functions like that

Comment: Oh shoot, I forgot it needs to be `loadMore={() => this.fetchCompanies(this.state.page)}`.  Leave the arrow function and try that.

Comment: same error still, problem is with the arrow function at this point =

Comment: I removed the arrow function and added the `bind` in the constructor

Comment: this way the loadmore keeps calling infinitely if you bind on constuctor. I had it like this actually!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171732/discussion-between-reed-dunkle-and-mizlul).